# 'name' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-' while trying to set the project name in a docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I put the following line at the top of my docker-compose.yml, to get a pre-set names for my containers spun by that particular docker-compose:

```
name: my_project_name
```

The goal is, for example, to have my database service container named "my_project_name_database".

However, after trying to start it with docker-compose up, I get the following error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> 'name' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'
> You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
> For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

This keeps happening no matter what version of docker-compose I specify.
What am I doing wrong in here? Is this the right way to set the project name at the docker-compose.yml level?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'd recommend not setting the top-level `name:` key, but do set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable if you need it.

```sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my_project_name
docker-compose up -d
```

The project name also defaults to the base name of the current directory, so renaming it is potentially an option.

```sh
cd ..
mv project my_project_name
cd my_project_name
docker-compose up -d
```

---

Docker has done some confusing things with the Compose file format.  They've introduced a [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element) which has some incompatibilities with the existing tooling, and then labeled the [existing](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) [versions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) that are well-supported by all reasonably-current versions of the Compose tool as "legacy".  The top-level `name:` key is new in the "specification" version, but not present in the "legacy" versions.

Neither Compose file version [2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) nor [3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) supports a top-level `name:` key.  If you're running the standalone `docker-compose` tool, there just isn't an option to set the project name in the Compose file.  But `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` works with all reasonably current versions of Compose.

If you run `docker-compose version` and it prints

```shellsession
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.9.0
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
```

then you can't use the Compose specification, but you can use the well-supported "legacy" versions.  But, if you run `docker compose version` (note, three words, no hyphen) and it prints

```shellsession
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.6.0
```

then you can use either the "legacy" versions or the "specification" version.

That is, if you use the "specification" extensions, then you must be using the most-recent version of Docker with the Compose extension installed, but if you use `version: '2.4'` or `version: '3.8'` then it will work with any more-or-less-current version of Compose.

---

The usual use case I see for setting `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` is to run multiple copies of the same Compose file at the same time.  For this you'll need to set the environment variable (and also to use environment variables for published `ports:`, and avoid manually setting `container_name:` or volume or network names); if it was a constant in the file then you'd have to edit it when working with one instance or the other of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by modifying the service name in the Dockerfile to be in **lowercase only**. This change resolved the problem and the application is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of docker-compose (the standalone tool), you can now use the compose plugin[1]. That works with the "name" parameter.

```
docker compose up
```

[1] https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command